# Is there a quick way to detect redirections?

Tags: apache, migration

I am migrating a website and it has many redirections. I would like to generate a list in which I can see all redirects, target and source.

I tried using Cyotek WebCopy but it seems to be unable to give the data I need. Is there a crawling method to do that? Or probably this can be accessed in Apache logs?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do it by crawling the website, but I advise against it in this specific situation, because there is an easier solution.

You use Apache, so you are (probably) working with HTTP/HTTPS protocol. You could refer to [HTTP referrer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer), if you use PHP, then you can reach the **previous page** via `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. So, you will need to do the following:

- figure out a way to store previous-next page pairs
- at the start of each request store such a pair, knowing what the [current URL](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-get-current-page-url-in-php.php) is and what the previous was
- maybe you will need to group your URLs and do some aggregation
- load the output somewhere and analyze